# How do I change behavior on write based on file path?

Tags: autocmd, functions

I have the following function in my config and it works fine for formatting files on save

```
  function! Formatonsave()
    let l:lines="all"
    if has('python')
      pyf ~/bin/clang-format.py
    elseif has('python3')
      py3f ~/bin/clang-format.py
    endif
  endfunction
  autocmd BufWritePre *.h,*.c,*.cc,*.cpp call Formatonsave()
```

However, when I'm working on the linux kernel (*.h, *.c) I don't want this function to be called.

How can I update either the function or the autocmd to skip the format if the file is in a certain path (or list of paths)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the easiest would be to add a check for the path in your function; for example:

```
function! Formatonsave()
    if expand('%:p') =~ expand('~/src/linux')
        return
    endif

    …
endfunction
```

`expand('%')` gets the path to the current buffer, and `:p` transforms that to a full path. You need to expand the right-hand of the expression for the `~` in there.

Alternatively, you can use something like:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.h,*.c,*.cc,*.cpp
        \  if expand('%:p') !~ expand('~/src/linux')
        \|    call Formatonsave()
        \| endif
```

Which is essentially the same thing.